# Issue of oneSignal integration in ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onesignal

I am integrating oneSignal push notification in React JS applciation. I found alot of help for react native but their is no documentation for react JS. So we start using Javscript for integration.

We are using Helmet modulee for putting oneSignal configuration in head tag but oneSignal is not getting initialized. 
Official documentation link of oneSignal is 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-typical-setup

```
render () {
if (this.state.isLoading) {
  return (
    <Loader/>
  )
}
return (  
<JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
    <div className="main-container">
      <Helmet>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
          var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
          OneSignal.push(function()
          OneSignal.init(
            appId: "a00000aa-000a-0ad0-aaa0-000a0aa0aa00",
            allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
          );
        );
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  </JssProvider>
)}}
```

Actually I have to put all this code into React JS header using helmet.  Please find this accepted answer. I have to do exactly same thing in react JS 
[OneSignal subscribe user through web page using web-push-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524751/onesignal-subscribe-user-through-web-page-using-web-push-sdk)

Comment: You code has a syntax error: the JS code that follows the script tag to include the OneSignal library is not wrapped in script tags, so it will do nothing

Comment: @PatrickHund Can you highlight where exactly is syntax error??

Comment: The javascript code block starting with "var OneSignal" needs to be wrapped in a script tag.

Comment: Even then, it won't work, though. This is JSX code, not HTML, so you'll have to use dangerouslySetInnerHtml. Please do some research on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put it in your public/index.html? (which is also the directory where you should put your SDK files)

I would encourage you to reach out to the onesignal.com support channel so we can look at your specific site

Comment: I placed all SDK files under public folder. Issue I am facing is different. I am unable to run oneSignal script in head using react JS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Helmet, but why don't you put it in your index.html file? This is an example React JS index.html file I created where it works: https://gist.github.com/rgomezp/ba303dc2e5101ab4897d284c55ed51cd

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo thanks for suggestion but index.html loads at very start of application and user should only subscribe after login but in your mention case it doesnt seems to work and secondly, all listener needs to be in react js file in order to navigate between component. If you have any example code on how to initiate oneSignal config in react js file then please share. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can initialize at the application load-time and simply not prompt the user until they are logged in. Please see our documentation for prompting: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/permission-requests

Answer (score 0):

You can check user is login or not then initialize one signal for example.
Place this cdn   `<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>` file inside head section in index.html 
if user is login then

```
this.initOneSignalNotification();
```

while your app is loaded first time.

else user is not login then call

```
this.initOneSignalNotification();
```

after user login. I thing this solution will fix your issue.

```
initOneSignalNotification(){
var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
          OneSignal.push(function()
          OneSignal.init(
            appId: "a00000aa-000a-0ad0-aaa0-000a0aa0aa00",
            allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
          );
        );
}
```

Comment: And how does this look in the final solution? It does not seem to work as expected.